# Data Warehousing design (with SSAS in mind)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, olap

I'm designing a data warehouse system, and have a question over the structure. First, here is some background into it (financial services):

There are a number of fee definitions defined (transaction fee, setup fee, SMS reminder fee and so on).

These fees can be updated and added (Dimension table).

There are payments defined that use a fee definition. A payment can contain 1 or more fee's, and the fee amount (and who pays) is unique to that payment (a transaction fee will be vastly different on a $2 transaction to that of a $2,000 transaction).

If I was designing an OLTP database, I would have the following:

- Payments (payment details)
- PaymentFees (FK to fee, FK to payment, fee amount, fee payee)
- Fees (fee name, group name etc)

My question is, how should I design this in a DW? I'm going to use SSAS for cube browsing, and I've heard that it doesn't handle many to many particularly well.

Comment: It handles many to many pretty well. http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/many2many/ You probably need to use many to many, because if start using where all fees are in fact table if somebody want to add new fee you need to add new column in payments...

Answer (score 0):

You can use many to many but it should be easier to build two fact tables (one for payments and one for fees, in both only store FK and $) and two dimensions (one for payment and another for fees but store all literals fields: name, group name). The solution with two dimensions will probably be easier to design and to understand for your end-users.